# ¿como realizar un filtro en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, tablas, filtro

estoy realizando un proyecto en laravel, donde quiero imprimir un reporte con informacion relacionada a una empresa, pero para poder imprimir este reporte tengo que realizar un filtrado de informacion de manera que no me traiga toda la base de datos sino que que solo la informacion con la empresa, me podrian ayudar porfavor!!!

> El mysql seria una consulta masomenos asi:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE company_id LIKE '%2%';
```

pero en laravel es diferente y ESTO ES LO QUE TENGO...

> CONTROLADOR **UsuariosController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;      //MODELO USER
use App\Company;   //MODELO COMPANY
class UsuariosController extends Controller

{
    public function listado(Request $request){
    $usuarios = User::query();
    $company_id = $request->company_id;
    if(!empty($company_id)){
        $usuarios = $usuarios->where('company_id', $company_id);
        }
    $usuarios = $usuarios->get(); 
    $tipos = Company::all();
    
    return view('CompanyInformation.usuarios')->with(compact('usuarios', 'tipos'));
    }
}
```

> RUTA:

```
Route::get('/listausuarios', 'UsuariosController@listado')->name('listado');
```

> VISTA **usuarios**

```
<form action="{{ route('listado') }}" method="GET">


<select name="company_id">
      <option value="">Selecciona una opción</option>
      @foreach($tipos as $tipo)
         <option value="{{ $tipo->id }}">{{ $tipo->nombre }}</option>
      @endforeach
   </select>
   <br>
   <button type="submit">Ver Usuarios</button>
</form>

<table>
   <tr>
      <td>id</td>
      <td>nombre</td>
      <td>apellido</td>
   </tr>
   @foreach($usuarios as $usuario)
   <tr>
      <td>{{ $usuario->id }}</td>
      <td>{{ $usuario->nombre }}</td>
      <td>{{ $usuario->apellido }}</td>
   </tr>
   @endforeach
</table>
```

Comment: que quieres traer exactamente

Comment: quiero traer el nombre y apellido de todos los ususarios que tengan el ID de la compañia que elija,
mi tabla Usuarios cuenta con los siguientes campos
**Id   Nombre   Apellido    CompanyId**

Comment: Ya no gracias, si sirve este filtro solo que mandaba a llamar mal mis variables de la tabla de la base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Traer los usuarios de una compañia:

```
$compañia= Company::first();
$usuariosDeLaCompañia = $compañia->users;

$usuariosDeLacompañiaQueMidanMasDe2Metros = $compañia->users()->where('estatura','>',2)->get()

$elPrimerApellidoDeLosUsuariosQueMidanMasDe2MetrosDeLaMismaCompañiaQueAntes = $compañia->users()->select('primer_apellido')->where('estatura','>',2)->get();
```

Espero que te sirva las diferentes formas de acceder a relaciones filtradas con eloquent con esos bastos ejemplos.

Si necesita otra aclaracion edito la respuesta.

Comment: muchisimas gracias, analizando mi codigo con el tuyo me di cuenta que el filtrado que realice si sirvfve solo que mande a llamar las variables mal
de igual manera agradezco tu ayuda

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a los `requerimientos` que necesitas, podrías utilizar estas instrucciones indicándole las `columnas` específicas que deseas ver **con y sin** la instrucción `where`.

Aquí unos ejemplos:

```
$variable = DB::table('nombre_tabla')->select('columna1','columna2')->get();

$variable2 = User::select('columna1','columna2')->where('company_id',  $company_id)->get();
```

Ya solo es cuestión de que las manipules de acuerdo a tus necesidades.

Answer (score 0):

me funcionaron muy bien pero mejore el codigo de manera que lo acorte para que no se ejecute tantos querys a la vez

```
if (!empty($request->company_id)) {
            $Accounts = Account::where('company_id', $request->company_id)->with('types')->with('company')->get(); //Obtener los valores 
            return View('CompanyInformation.accuonts', compact('Accounts'));//generala vista
           
        }
```

Comment: ¿por qué tanto with por separado?